# How to render cached images React

Tags: reactjs, caching

I'm fetching images from urls (e.g. https:/xxxxx/xxxx.jpeg)
and caching them afterwards. they appear in the cache tab in my dev tools.
The question is how can I render them to an `<img/>` element for instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using the exact path of the image you see jn the cache tab as the contents of the src="" tag :)

Comment: Actually I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I see you are running the website on your localhost! Please make sure that the path to your images is the correct path, otherwise use relative paths

Comment: This was confusing for me. Having known that the images are cached in memory not as file got me confused with which path should I use. It would be nice to illustrate with an example. Thank you.

Comment: well, do you have those images in a folder/directory as well? Or are they only present in cache memory?

Comment: I fetch them. I don't have them in a folder. That's the problem.